# Connect to ethernet via terminal without ifconfig / others

Tags: drivers, nvidia, ethernet, zorin

My Nvidia Drivers are broken, I can't boot up my Zorin OS (Ubuntu 18.04) system, so I entered recovery mode, and purged the drivers using `apt-get`.

But when trying to install another version (450) I see that I have no internet connection.

I can't use `net-tools`, I don't have them installed, and I also can't use DHCP, the command doesn't exist either.

Using `ip link enp5s0 up` also doesn't work (shows the device as down anyways on `ip addr`).

So I'm stuck, cause I can't connect to my wired connection and can't install any drivers.

Any other way to connect to my internet connection? (If I'm not able to do this, I'll not be able to install the fixed 455 drivers when they come out anyways, so I'm kinda doomed.)

I wasn't able to open the terminal using Ctrl+Alt+F1/F6/F7.
When booting up Zorin OS **regularly**, [this is what I see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5283H.jpg)

I don't know how the recovery mode really works, I just know it let's me use the terminal as a superuser and show some another options. [This is the menu I get on recovery mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PUAMh.jpg).

**Running with**:
AMD 7 3700X and RTX 2070 Super (looks like Nvidia 455 is not working for rtx cards)

Comment: I executed apt-get purge nvidia*, I need to install the nvidia-driver-450 ones. The system does boot, but shows nothing on the screen but a wallpaper, because the nvidia-driver-455 ones are broken for rtx cards. And yes, i mean recovery mode, i haven't got internet connection in the recovery mode's terminal.

Comment: I tried Ctrl+Alt+F1 / F6 / F7. None of them work, I'll try F3 when I get home. This is my screen when I boot up, doesn't look like it'll show a terminal there. My screen after I boot: https://imgur.com/a/V5GY87r

Comment: The question should explain whether "recovery mode" means booting from some other device or disc volume, or booting the _usual_ operating system to `rescue.target`.

Comment: I added some information to the post. Thanks in advance to all of you.

Comment: It's informative to answerers to be specific because different people mean different things by this, thanks in part to differences among operating systems, and bootstrapping the usual operating system to `rescue.target` is differently convertible into a state where networking is running, than bootstrapping from (say) another removable device that executes a menu-based system of administrative tools is.

Comment: 1) To make sure: the suggestion of typing Ctrl+Alt+F1 (or F2, F3...) assumed you were not in recovery mode (where additional virtual terminals may not be set up on purpose). Did you also try Ctrl+Alt+... when booting normally? 2) The recovery menu in the screenshot you linked to also has a "network" option. You should try selecting it before the "root" one.

Comment: I tried Ctrl+Alt+F1 / F6 / F7 booting normally. I didn't realize about the "Network" option! I'll give that a try when I get home, thanks.